# "generate-pch command failed with exit code 1" when making a new Xcode scheme

Tags: xcode, cocoa, cocoapods, development-environment

I'm following the instruction here http://www.teratotech.com/blog/xcode-7-steps-to-easily-switch-between-multiple-environments/ to generate different schemes for different environments..

I created a `testing configuration` and created a new scheme to use that configuration. However, when I build and run, I'm getting this error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: generate-pch command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

 error: 'AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h' file not found
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>

1 error generated.
<unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '/var/folders/f2/6j4b4kz54xy1vf_2gdlnrllc0000gn/T/My-Project-Header-47bffb.pch' for bridging header '/Users/me/Dev/my-project/My-Project-Header.h'
```

When I build with my original scheme, everything's fine... I only have 1 target. Am I missing anything?

EDIT: I'm using Cocoapods to manage my dependencies, if that makes any difference.

Comment: `sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` helped!

Comment: change bridging header path in build setting with `$(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/My-Project-Header.h`

Answer (score 3):

i solved this issue by running below commands

```
$ pod repo update
$ pod install
```

Usually such issue happens when project directory is changed or copied form some other machine.

Comment: this should be answer